# Declaring two dummy variables for two separate variables in R?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

Suppose my category is color and my categorical variables are "red", "orange" and "blue".

And I want to regress my model on the two variables is_blue and is_red, where is_blue is 1 when it's blue (0 otherwise) and is_red is 1 when it's red (0 otherwise).

How would I be able to use my categorical variables twice?

Comment: What do you mean by "use my categorical variables twice"?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without clear data details, but is this what you want?

```
set.seed(100)
dat<- data.frame(
color=rep(c("red", "orange", "blue"),each=10)
,
var=rnorm(3*10,20,1)
)
levels(dat$color)
dat$is_red=ifelse(dat$color=="red",1,0)
dat$is_blue=ifelse(dat$color=="blue",1,0)
lm(var~is_blue+is_red,dat)
lm(var~factor(color),dat) #base blue
lm(var ~ C(color,contr.treatment(3, base=2)), data=dat )

> lm(var~is_blue+is_red,dat)

Call:
lm(formula = var ~ is_blue + is_red, data = dat)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      is_blue       is_red  
    20.2337      -0.3628      -0.2516  

> lm(var~factor(color),dat) #base blue

Call:
lm(formula = var ~ factor(color), data = dat)

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)  factor(color)orange     factor(color)red  
            19.8709               0.3628               0.1112  

> lm(var ~ C(color,contr.treatment(3, base=2)), data=dat )

Call:
lm(formula = var ~ C(color, contr.treatment(3, base = 2)), data = dat)

Coefficients:
                            (Intercept)  C(color, contr.treatment(3, base = 2))1  
                                20.2337                                  -0.3628  
C(color, contr.treatment(3, base = 2))3  
                                -0.2516
```